# CFURLRef of documents directory

Tags: iphone

I am creating an app that needs access to the documents directory. I am currently using the following to return the URL of a file `pdfName` from the main bundle. Is there a similar way of getting the documents directory?

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), (CFStringRef)pdfName, NULL, NULL);
```

Edit: **this is my full code, but it isn't working - any ideas?**

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:pdfName];

    CFURLRef pdfURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:myFilePath];
    pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
    CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem. The app crashed when creating the CFURLRef. This is how i solved it (given you already have an NSString with the complete path to the file in documents directory):

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:myFilePath];
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
CFRelease(pdfURL);
```

Looks like the only difference in my code is that I alloc and init the NSURL.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: [ADC Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Articles/StandardDirectories.html)

Comment: I had a look into that and made some progress (see update above). Any ideas on what is wrong with my current code?

Comment: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains returns a NSArray see http://bit.ly/g7pNrF and I found an example on the web http://bit.ly/fSbJLY :) hope it helps.